How do I create a cumulative graphic for the last 12 months?
I'm new in PowerBI, and I have a hard time doing something that shouldn't be that hard. I think I don't have the logic of the product yet. My Google search doesn't help me here.
Let's imagine I have the following source:



Quantity
Fruit
StartDate
EndDate




12
Apples
13/07/2023
15/09/2025


7
Apples
17/11/2023
15/02/2023


32
Peaches
19/11/2023
20/03/2026


26
Apples
19/11/2023
01/01/2025


12
Apples
17/01/2024
17/01/2026


19
Peaches
02/02/2024
02/02/2028




Fruit : types of fruits
StartDate : Day where I've got the fruit
EndDate : Date when I will lose the fruit

I want to perform a graphic, on the last 12 months from the active date, which give my total number of combined fruits, by differentiating apples and peaches, in my possession, for each month.
My issues are the following:

I don't understand how to sum correctly my fruits, all the graphic are only giving me the sum for the current month (what is the number of Fruits I've win on a specific timeframe) and not the overall sum
I don't understand how to do a rolling graphic on a windows of the last 12 months, every date you can tell is only during a fixed year. // Edit : I've found a start of a solution here (Display last 12 months) but not sure to understand it: I have to create a separate calendar table?

Thank you a lot for your help.
